# Windows Explorer blacks out and then loads file lists slowly one by one

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

This has been an issue for months, the gif shows the issue. I open a folder with files in it, the window blacks out and then loads the list one by one:

[image]

I've tried disabling indexing, but that didn't solve the issue, and searching for other people with this problem doesn't lead anywhere.

Hardware: Asus G15, 5900HS, 3070(8gb), 32GB RAM, 1TB NVME OS Drive, 1TB NVME Storage, Windows 11 22H2 22621.2134

Issue persists on both SSDs, also had this happen on windows 10 before upgrading to windows 11. Machine is otherwise very fast, this is the only issue I have. Seems to be worse when viewing folders full of large items like video files. Strangely, if the list is too long to display, it will load each file line by line, but then when it reaches the bottom of the list that can be displayed, it loads the rest (offscreen) instantly. So this is somehow tied to displayed items.

Any help would be appreciated in figuring this out!

Comment: What video player apps do you have? Is it possible one you have set as default is trying to handle thumbnail duties and isn't doing an efficient job creating and caching them? If you've installed any sort of video player, I'd uninstall it. Also, change the folder view to remove thumbnails and see if the folder contents load/display more quickly.

Comment: This isn't an indexing issue _(even with thousands of files, once indexed, they're indexed and that would graphically present differently)_. If it's an OS issue, the most efficient way to resolve is going to be a repair install rather than trying to troubleshoot - repair installs usually take less time to complete than troubleshooting, especially with you having the issue for a while. To do a repair install, use the Media Creation Tool to download the install ISO, extract it, then run `setup.exe` _while still booted to Windows_, choosing to _Keep Everything_

Comment: First step to troubleshoot this should be trying it in safe mode. If it occurs there, then it's 100% something that needs a system repair. If not, disabling software that can mess with Explorer one by one, in Autoruns, could provide you a culprit.